# Schema Refinement

Tags: database-design

I want to create a database for an apparel management system. I have created two tables for the quantity of a particular garment.

- 1st form:

  ```
  Ord_ID | XXXS |  XXS |  XS |  S |  M |  L |  XL |  XXL |  3XL |  4XL | Tot
  ```
- 2nd form:

  ```
  Ord_ID | qty | type
  ```

  Types are *xxxs*, *xxs*, *xs*, *s*, *m*, *l*, *xl*, *xxl*, *3xl*, *4xl*.

In the 1st form it creates a lot of null values.

In the 2nd form *ord_id* is repeated many times.

Which method should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

You should use 2-nd method, because if you will be use 1-st method you will be have the problems for example with print forms and more complex problems in futures.